# Improve fetch rows from database and save into array

Tags: php, mysqli

I am building a backend solution for our company right now.

So far so good, the issue is, that mysqlnd is not installed on our company server, so I cannot use this solution:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch_all()){
$rows[] = $row; }
```

Instead I am using this code:

```
 if($db){
        $arrayId = 0;
        $result = array();
        $sql = "select Company.id, Company.status, Company.balance, Order.City, Order.street from Company join Order on Company.Order_id = Order.id where Company.id = ?;";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
        if($stmt->execute() === true){
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $status, $balance, $city, $street);
         while($stmt->fetch()){
           $result[$arrayId][0] = $id;
           $result[$arrayId][1] = $status;
           $result[$arrayId][2] = $balance;
           $result[$arrayId][3] = $city;
           $result[$arrayId][4] = $street;

            $arrayId++;
        }
            $stmt->close();
            return $result;
        }
```

I am pretty sure, that there is a way to improve that, I really like the other solution, because it is logically and easy to use. Maybe someone can give me a hint, how to change my code.

Thanks!
Jan

Comment: $result[] = [$id, $status, $balance, $city, $street];

Comment: If in 2020 your server still does not offer mysqlnd then you need to change host.

Comment: Also, if you can try to use PDO which is simpler and does not have such problems

Comment: Thanks common sense, that is working.

Comment: @Dharman Is it easy to migrate from mysql to mysqlnd? Or is it more work then just remove one package and add another? If it is not too hard I will ask my boss if we can do it

Comment: There should be no difference for you. Also, the old library is called libmysqlclient. It comes down to what PHP was compiled with.